# Ember build for production took more than expected time

Tags: node.js, windows, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm developing an Ember application, in that application

Building application for production environment gives following warning during build process.

```
>>ember build --environment production
WARNING: Node v7.2.1 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS" version of Node.js.
/ Building[WARN] `assets/vendor.js` took: 27201ms (more than 20,000ms)
cleaning up...
Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".
File sizes:
 - dist/assets/vendor-55a426e75e5239020a12bb7bfc6ffc2a.js: 759.74 KB (195.13 KB gzipped)
 - dist/assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css: 0 B
```

i want to suppress these waning messages, for this i tried --silent with command.

```
ember build --environment production --silent
```

Still im getting following warning:

```
[WARN] `assets/vendor.js` took: 27201ms (more than 20,000ms)
```

cam some one tell me how to suppress this warning or fix this?

**OS**: Windows 2012 R2 server

Comment: Are you running the command as administrator?  Non-admin accounts take a very long time to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in broccoli-uglify-sourcemap, I have opened an issue to track & fix:

https://github.com/ef4/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/issues/38

---

I have released a new version of broccoli-uglify-sourcemap (v1.5.1) which now abides by --silent and also provides a better warning message.

Your issue should vanish once this dependency upgrades.

The following command can be used to confirm you are atleast at v1.5.1

`npm ls broccoli-uglify-sourcemap`